# What is the recommended way to package perl scripts for CPAN (and CorporatePAN)?

Tags: windows, linux, perl, packaging, cpan

Recently I looked at a module on CPAN that comes with a script to be installed
which made me wonder. What is the recommended way to include a script in a package
that should end up on the public CPAN and if there is any different recommendation for
packages that would be released on an in-house CPAN server?

The script starts like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

eval 'exec /usr/bin/perl  -S $0 ${1+"$@"}'
  if 0; # not running under some shell
```

Two questions

Do I understand correctly the eval part is unnecessary? 
That will be embedded by the CPAN client during installation and it 
will be very different when installing on Windows.

What is the recommended sh-bang line?
Would that be

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
```

instead of the above?

Answer (score 6):

Just use

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
```

(Or, optionally, whatever the path to `perl` is on your development machine.)

When Module::Build or MakeMaker installs your script, it will change the `#!` line to match the `perl` that is installing the module.  It will also add the "eval exec" lines, except under Windows, where it will create a `.bat` file instead.  (The CPAN client has nothing to do with this.)

If you use

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
```

then the installers won't realize that's a Perl script, and will not modify the `#!` line.

Answer (score 3):

When the distribution is being installed, it is being installed *for some particular perl*, and should explicitly set the #! to use that perl (as given in `$Config{startperl}`).  As far as I know all the module installers do this for you.  (Update: as noted by cjm, only if the #! as distributed runs perl, not env.)

The eval stuff is traditionally included to automatically use perl even if a script is invoked with `sh scriptname`.  It's harmless.

Comment: Actually, the `eval` is because the `#!` [wasn't invented](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29#History) until Version 8 Unix.  Earlier versions just assumed an executable text file must be a shell script.